# How do I get the amount of bandwidth used during the execution of a Linux program?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, linux

I need to understand how much bandwidth is used by a program which I execute from a shell on Linux, via subprocess.run in Python.

Maybe a solution already exists, something similar to `time`?

```
petur@petur:~$ time foobar
foobar  0.00s user 0.00s system 80% cpu 0.003 total
```

If not, what libraries would I need create such a utility? (To gather the total incoming and outgoing bandwidth during the execution of a program (including all of its threads/tasks)).

Comment: What do you mean by "bandwidth"? That term can apply to many different things.

Comment: If you mean *network* bandwidth, then your program can simply measure the amount of bytes it sends and receives, and when the program exits divide it by the time the program had been running.

Comment: BTW, insofar as this question isn't specific to software development, [unix.se] might be a better fit topicality-wise.

Comment: [Identical question asked on Server Fault.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77057463)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea to get you started, assuming you're talking about network bandwidth. We can trace all writes and reads to sockets using strace. Here's some example output when I run

```
strace curl example.org
# [...]
recvfrom(5, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nAge: 550983\r\nCa"..., 102400, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1591
# [...]
```

This line has information about a single call to the recvfrom system call. Importantly it tells us that the syscall returned 1591, which is the number of bytes read from the socket.

Another example line:

```
sendto(5, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.or"..., 74, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 74
```

This tells us that curl wrote 74 bytes to a socket.

So, as a first attempt to estimate the bandwidth used by a program, we can add up all the return values of send* syscalls and all the return values of recv* syscalls.

This isn't perfect - but in practice I suspect it's pretty good. Reasons that it's not perfect:

- there may be other syscalls that can cause network reads/writes
- the syscalls can return errors, which in this case are negative return values
- sockets can be used for local communication too

With that in mind, here's a simple bash function to do the job:

```
bandwidth() {
  traceout="$(mktemp -u)"
  mkfifo "$traceout"
  strace -o "$traceout" -e recv,recvfrom,recvmsg,send,sendto,sendmsg "$@" &

  awk <"$traceout" '
    BEGIN {rbytes = 0; sbytes = 0}
    /^send/ { sbytes += $NF }
    /^recv/ { rbytes += $NF }
    END {
      print "sent bytes:", sbytes;
      print "received bytes:", rbytes
    }'

  rm "$traceout"
}
```

Some example usage:

```
$ bandwidth curl -s -o/dev/null example.org
sent bytes: 178
received bytes: 1599

$ bandwidth curl -s -o/dev/null https://stackoverflow.com
sent bytes: 915
received bytes: 182259
```

Comment: There are much more efficient approaches available -- for example, you could create a cgroup and read its statistics for total bytes out and in. The major concern I have with strace here is the performance impact -- there are other much more efficient syscall-tracing tools available; see f/e ebpftrace or sysdig (really, writing a custom eBPF program that just manages the total in kernelspace is probably what makes the most sense if for some reason you couldn't go the cgroup approach).

Comment: BTW, you want `"$@"` in quotes, not bare `$@`; without the quotes `$@` acts like an unquoted `$*`, word-splitting and glob-expanding each argument.

Comment: This is good enough for my needs.
I am trying to understand how much bandwith is used by a python script that invokes pip using subprocess.run.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson you should update the strace command to `strace -f` in order to to account for child processes